# axios send wrong csrf cookie

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want process a POST request with axios in a vuejs project, but axios never send correct csrf cookie. My vuejs project run in dev mode on port 8080, my server (Spring Boot) on port 9090. I set correct CORS filter for localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080, OPTIONS is accepted, but I get a 403 error on my POST.

Here my code :

```js
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/security/authenticate", 
    this.form,
    {
        withCredentials: true,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'
    }
).then((response) => {
    console.log("Data: " + response.data);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("post error: " + error);
});
```

And here the result of my OPTIONS request on chromium :

```
GENERAL:
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/security/authenticate
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:9090
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS :
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 21:44:07 GMT
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers

REQUEST HEADERS :
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:9090
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/login
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
```

And my POST :

```
GENERAL:
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/security/authenticate
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:9090
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS :
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 21:44:07 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

REQUEST HEADERS :
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=428229a0-b2b1-4473-ab3a-557e4dbac1b1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9090
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/login
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36

REQUEST PAYLOAD :
{login: "xxx", password: "xxx", rememberme: false}
login: "xxx"
password: "xxx"
rememberme: false
```

The CSRF cookie sent (428229a0...) is not correct. Previously in a GET request, I obtained an other CSRF token (70705d00...). Why wrong csrf cookie was sent ?

To be sure that is not the result of dev mode from vuejs, I build my project and deploy it on nginx server, but I got same result. I try also on firefox, get same error.

In package.json, axios is in version "^0.19.0", vuejs "^2.6.10".

What is wrong in my code ? Or is about configuration of my server ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _"Previously in a GET request, I obtained an other CSRF token"_  seems this is the root of your problem. Try using your browser's dev-tools to monitor the cookie value. Are you seeing the correct cookie value in the response headers (ie `Set-cookie`) for that GET request?

Comment: Yes, I saw it. the csrf cookies for the GET request was 70705d00..., and Axios send cookies with 428229a0... where does this cookie come from?